# Difference of squares

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Determine if $5^{36} - 1$ is divisible by $13$ using the difference of squares.  I tried splitting it up by difference of squares a couple of times but can't seem to get to a point where I can determine divisibility.

Answer (score 2):

We have $5^{36}-1=(5^{18}+1)(5^{18}-1)$. Also, $5^{18}+1=(5^6)^3+1=(5^6+1)((5^6)^2-5^6+1)$, and $5^6+1=(5^2)^3+1=(5^2+1)((5^2)^2-5^2+1)$. We are done, because $5^2+1=26=2\cdot13$.

Comment: thanks for the help... had some minor errors in my steps

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$5^{36}-1=(5^{18}-1)(5^{18}+1)$$

$$5^{18}-1=(5^9-1)(5^9+1)$$

$$5^9-1=(5-1)(5^8+5^7+\ldots+5+1)\;\;,\;\;5^9+1=(5+1)(5^8-5^7+\ldots-5+1)$$

Comment: I think factoring out $5^4-1$ would be better.

Comment: Yes, me too...but I thought the OP might not know modular arithmetic so a rather naive approach could serve him better...

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$5^2 \equiv -1$ mod 13

also we know,
$a \equiv b$ mod 13 $\Rightarrow a^2 \equiv b^2$ mod 13 etc.

Congruences are nothing but the difference of squares written in a fancy way.

Comment: Or, as I prefer to think about it, the difference of squares formula is just a congruence written in a non-fancy way.

Comment: alright I got it now thanks for the help